# Slick slider custom dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, slick.js

I was wondering if there is a way to use custom slick slider dots. When I search, all I can finds is examples on how to change the dots into thumbnails from the slides, however this is not what I'm trying to accomplish. I just want to use my own png pictures for the active and non-active dot navigation. I tried this:

```
    $('.slick-dots li').html('<a href="#"><img src="slide-dot.png" /></a>');
    $('.slick-dots li.slick-active').html('<a href="#"><img src="slide-dot-active.png" /></a>');
```

But that didn't work, though I recall I did something like that before. Am I missing something here ?

Thanks!

Comment: any console error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can style slick dots with CSS only and avoid using inline images:

Using background image:

```
.slick-dots li button {
    background: url(path/to/your-image.png);
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow:hidden;
    /* more CSS */
}
```

Using pseudo element:

```
.slick-dots li button {
    font-size: 0;
    /* more CSS */
}
.slick-dots li button {
    content:url(path/to/your-image.png);
}
```

Answer (score 26):

This can be done when initializing slick as one of the options:

JS

```
$(".slider").slick({
    dots: true,
    customPaging : function(slider, i) {
        return '<a href="#"><img src="slide-dot.png" /><img src="slide-dot-active.png" /></a>';
    },
});
```

Then you can display the image you want based on the active state with CSS

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

.slick-dots li img:nth-child(1) {
    display: block;
}

.slick-dots li img:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}

.slick-dots li.slick-active img:nth-child(1) {
    display: none;
}

.slick-dots li.slick-active img:nth-child(2) {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Can you please make any jsfiddle or codepen to understand in easy way?

Comment: Do you have an active code example to build off of? That's probably the better way of helping.

Comment: Note if you're an idiot like me you need to use the `<a>` tags in the returned HTML.

Answer (score 8):

Hello there i searched a lot but didn't find any solution so i created my own solution

you can do like this:

In `html`

```html
<div class="card rounded-0 h-100">
    <div class="card-body p-0">
        <div id="slick-slider">
            <a href="#"><img class="w-100" src="https://demo.activeitzone.com/ecommerce/public/uploads/all/kYLM906MNqYcHvm0bHLcIj3TxldjZfySHl26wHMu.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="#"><img class="w-100" src="https://demo.activeitzone.com/ecommerce/public/uploads/all/ppB6tYYNgWM3vL3uq81n80fZCdxrgkMul9KPk9pm.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="#"><img class="w-100" src="https://demo.activeitzone.com/ecommerce/public/uploads/all/Dp0DBHFbBuyRCAUi8Od6tk4izOsMg1mVB1v8QAeu.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-slider-nav"></div>
        <div class="slick-slider-dots"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in `javascript`

```js
$('#slick-slider').slick({
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    appendArrows: $('.slick-slider-nav'),
    appendDots: $('.slick-slider-dots'),
    prevArrow: "<button class='slick-prev btn btn-white rounded-circle'><i class='mdi mdi-chevron-left'></i></button>",
    nextArrow: "<button class='slick-next btn btn-white rounded-circle'><i class='mdi mdi-chevron-right'></i></button>",
});
```

For dots style like this i am using `SCSS`

```
.slick-slider-dots{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: flex;

    ul {
        display: flex;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

        li {
            margin: 0 4px;
            button {
                background: $gray-200;
                height: 8px;
                width: 35px;
                overflow: hidden;
                color: $gray-200;
                border: none;
                border-radius: 4px;
            }
            &.slick-active {
                button {
                    background: $primary;
                    color: $primary;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Dots will look like this
[image]

Comment: very cool one! Thanks for sharing. Where are the icons from?

Comment: @StefanYYC which icons you are talking about?

Comment: this one `<i class='mdi mdi-chevron-right'></i>`

Comment: @StefanYYC They are the material design icons you can get from this cdn
```<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/MaterialDesign-Webfont/5.9.55/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"/>```

Answer (score 4):

you can use the option "appendDots" when initializing the slider.
For example: appendDots: '$('.your-dot')'

Comment: doesn't this just specify under which element the dots are added?

Comment: thx, `appendDots` attaches the dots into desired location

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this simply by using CSS, and you don't need any JavaScript function.

1- choose the element you want the slider to be applied to

this code is `pugjs`

```
ul
  li 01
  li 02
  li 03
  li 04
  li 05
```

2- Then apply the Slider function to this element

```
$("ul").slick()
```

3- Now add the dot feature to the slider and do it with true

```
$("ul").slick({
  dots: true,
})
```

4- Now go to the points and click on them and open the console and drag the class named `slick-dots`

5- Add the formatting you want to the buttons inside, as shown in the following figure

```
.slick-dots li button
{
  width:10px;height:10px;
  background-color:red;border-radius:50%;
  font-size:0px; // This step is very important to hide the numbers
  border:0;
}
```

6- Now inside the console, **you will notice the mechanism of action of this slider**, as it puts an **active** class on the element that you click on, so we go to the css and we coordinate the active

```
.slick-dots .slick-active button
{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

7- And in this way, you will end the customization of dot without the need for any JavaScript function.